# React Native Location Switch

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

The **ReactNativeAndroidLocationSwitch** pod failed to validate due to 1 error: - ERROR | attributes: Missing required attribute homepage. - WARN | source: The version should be included in the Git tag. - WARN | description: The description is equal to the summary.

Answer (score 0):

yarn add philiWeitz/react-native-location-switch#pull/21/head